# All 2013 Workflow Actions Appear Twice in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have both 2010 and 2013 Workflows enabled. When creating a 2010 workflow, there is no issue. When creating a 2013 workflow, every action in the Action drop-down list is duplicated. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the problem and am posting a follow-up just in case anyone runs into this same problem in the future. I made a backup copy of the workflow15.actions4 file and left it in the same folder with a different name but the same file extension. I believe SharePoint reads any files with that extension in that folder regardless of the name. So it was seeing the actions (and conditions I later found) twice.

I moved my backup copy to a folder on the desktop and eventually (I suppose after SharePoint propagated the changes) it went back to normal. So if anyone runs into this problem, check your workflow folder on the SharePoint server (Default location: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\1033\Workflow\ ) and make sure there is only 1 .actions4 file (for 2013 workflows) and if applicable only 1 .actions file (for 2010 workflows). They will be named workflow15.actions4 and WSS.ACTIONS respectively.